# Writing scope ({) into string in console app

Tags: c#, string, console-application

I am trying to write a code generator using a c# console application. Now when I type this, I receive an error:

```
    Console.WriteLine("sphere {{0}{1} {2} texture{Gold_Metal}}", 
    pre, i.ToString(), sprad.ToString());
```

It says "input in wrong format" I have checked that all the variables were strings, and they are. When I tried

```
    Console.WriteLine("sphere {0}{1} {2} textureGold_Metal", 
    pre, i.ToString(), sprad.ToString());
```

It worked perfectly fine. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Just escape curly braces with themselves where you need to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you want a literal `{` inserted into the stream, you need to escape a your `{` with yet *another* brace thus:

```
Console.WriteLine("sphere {{{0}{1} {2} ...
                          ^^
                          ||-- see here.
```

Similarly for the end-brace, this is detailed in the MSDN string formatting FAQ [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa569608). The sequence `{{` becomes `{` and `}}` becomes `}`.

From what I understand your intent to be, the full statement in your specific case would be:

```
Console.WriteLine("sphere {{{0}{1} {2} texture{{Gold_Metal}}}}", 
    pre, i.ToString(), sprad.ToString());
```

which should give you something like:

```
sphere {<Arg0><Arg1> <Arg2> texture{Gold_Metal}}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `{{` to "escape" the curly brace. `Writeln` interprets `{{0}` as 'literal {' followed by `0}`, resulting in the wrong format error.

Answer (score 0):

Change what you have to write this and see if it works.. also make sure that you are converting the variable types where you have .ToString(); would need to know what the actual declared types are.. paste the code in where you have declared pre, sprad, and i

```
 Console.WriteLine(string.Format("sphere {0}{1} {2} textureGold_Metal", 
    pre, i.ToString(), sprad.ToString()));
```